# Add Order Programmatically

Tags: magento2, orders, programmatically

Hi i want add order Programmatically using magento 2
So i need A custom REST API something like

```
/V1/order/add/:sku/:item_id/:qty/:user_id
```

Comment: i found this solution but for magento 1.X
http://inchoo.net/magento/programmatically-create-order-in-magento/
i need some thinc like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple and interesting. Read these Link carefully

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877767/create-order-programmatically-in-magento
2. http://www.blog.plazathemes.com/archives/2149